# JS Function "Object expected At line 2 character 0"

Tags: javascript, function, object, number-formatting

I'm building a plan file for XMPie Uplan.  Javascript functions are allowed, so as I am learning JS, I thought I would take advantage of them.  They seem friendlier than the proprietary QLingo functions.  I don't think that should matter though, it is just JS.  Anyone see a problem with my JS?

```
function cents(p) {
var monfor = toString(parseFloat(Math.round(p * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
return monfor.slice(-2);
}
```

The purpose of this code is to return just the cents in a price.

Here is what is supposed to be going on: 
First I make sure the number has two decimal places and convert to a string.  Then I slice off the last two digits of my string leaving me with a 2 digit integer as a string which is the number of pennies in my price.  This will flow into the cents portion of a price field with the cents in superscript.  (I have another function that uses floor to kill the sub dollar part of the price that populates the dollar part of the price.)  The error on this function is:

```
Error:        cents: An error occurred while executing the function script. 
Description: Object expected At line 2 character 0.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is this `toString()` coming from? Besides that, `Number.prototype.toFixed()` already returns a string

Comment: `toString` needs context. Actually you can just remove it, since `toFixed` converts to string too. Btw. this won't fire an error in all browsers, but returns unexpected result instead.

Comment: `toString` is `window.toString` which is available as `toString` because it's part of the global object.

Comment: Killing toString works wonderfully.  THANKS SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
var numToParse = parseFloat(Math.round(p * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

var monfor = numToParse.toString();
return monfor.slice(-2);
```

You were using the two string in the wrong way.

As mentioned in the comments, i didnt know this, you dont even need to parse it to string as the toFixed() parses it itself.

```
var monfor = parseFloat(Math.round(p * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
return monfor.slice(-2);
```

Comment: You are right, but so is Teemu who suggested just killing toString as it is not needed.  THANKS SO MUCH everyone!